# How RDP authentication work?

Tags: authentication, remote-desktop, rdp

I am trying to understand the RDP Protocol architecture. I tried to capture the packet between two PC which connected through Remote Desktop Connection under Windows 7 using Wireshark. I found the protocol is ms-wbt-server instead of RDP. For my understanding, windows remote desktop connection is using rdp protocol, and from the packet I found alot Continuation under TPKT protocol, but I don't understand what is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [RDP protocol specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240445.aspx). There are other related specs in [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj712081.aspx); just search for "Remote Desktop" on the page.